# How does the Raza (season 2 episode 8) have the blink drive?

Tags: dark-matter

In the episode [Stuff to Steal, People to Kill](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt5578258/) the crew figures out that they are in an alternate reality due to a misconfiguration of the blink drive.  They quickly see an alternate Raza using the blink drive successfully.

We learn a few things throughout the course of this episode:

- 6 is dead, being killed by 2 while recording a message to GA
- 5 seemingly never made it on board, thus not saving 6

5 not being there is an assumption.  She could have made it on board, and then been killed by the crew, but at one point she meets the alternate crew and they don't seem to recognize her.

How does the alternate reality Raza crew have the blink drive if 5 never made it on board with the key?  Perhaps they were given it by the mining company to help win the war for them?

Comment: I can improve the question if I did something wrong :(

Comment: We have to assume that the alternate Raza crew didn't lose their memories, learnt about the drive, and made a raid to get it and the keys.  There's no reason they would need 5 for that.

Real answer is that we don't know, but I'm betting that's what happened.

Comment: @Tim I kind of figured it was a "we don't know" but I was unsure if there was something I was missing.

Comment: I do not believe we have been given any specifics as to how they got the blink drive. I am hoping we will learn more about the AU crew this season. It would seem that at some point this season(3) we will see Wexler at least...